# is there any Linux software for extracting "close caption" out of "generic" tv cards?

Tags: linux, tuner-card

The title say it all.

Is there any software for linux (preferably ubuntu) that let me save the close
captions on some tv shows to a file?

I just need to extract the closed captions isn't necessary any video optput.

i don't know if this required hardware support that is why i'm asking support for generic tv cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [CCExtractor](http://ccextractor.sourceforge.net/). You need to compile it from source though.
It takes MPEG files as input, so you'll need to save the input stream somewhere and try it out.

Comment: this means capturing the stream first, so he'll need to install capture software.  mythbuntu's hardware compatibility list is a good place to start getting the tv card up and running: http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Tuner_Card#Cards_that_work